# Magento Catalog Advanced Search Pagination Issue

Tags: php, magento, pagination

In the Catalog Advanced Search Page I am not able to see the pagination. I am having one brand in my magento store and if my brand having not more than 36 products pagination is coming. And when i add more than 36 products in to this brand, pagination disappears.

Can you please help me in that.

My Site URL is : http://homefurnituretrading.co.uk/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer%5B%5D=164

My Code in the catalogsearch.xml is :

```
<reference name="content">
         <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>                
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block> 
</reference>
```

Thanks, Ali

Answer (score 0):

add below code above the `<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>` tag

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">

<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

</block>

<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
```

and add the same code above the column count of `<catalogsearch_advanced_result>` tag

clear the cache and test it again

Comment: this issues occurs after 36 products found in the result. Till 36 it works fine..